# Manage Large Table

Tags: tables

Can someone help me with the large table? It does not matter if you want to use `\begin{sidewaystable}` or `\begin{table}`. The table is too big, I cannot read what is inside the cells. would you please adjust the table for me?

My attempt:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{graphicx} %---> %---> %---> DO NOT ALTER THIS COMMAND
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}% http://ctan.org/pkg/rotating
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{rotfloat}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}         
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{collcell}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{graphics}
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{10}
\pagestyle{myheadings} \textheight 8in \textwidth 6.5in
\oddsidemargin -0in \evensidemargin 0in \topmargin 0.1in
\newcommand{\mbf}[1]{\mbox{\boldmath $#1$}}
\newcommand{\thetheorem}{{\thesection. \arabic{theorem}}}
\newcommand{\thelemma}{{\thesection. \arabic{lemma}}}
\newcommand{\theproposition}{{\thesection. \arabic{proposition}}}
\newcommand{\thecorollary}{{\thesection. \arabic{corollary}}}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[section]
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[section]
\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}[H]
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
\caption{Mean and standard deviation of ......AR${(1)}$.} 
\begin{center}
\begin{adjustbox}{width=1\textwidth, center}
\begin{tabular}{|c| c| c| c| c| c|  c| c| c| c| c| c| c|  c| c| c| c| c| c| c|  c| c|}
\hline \hline
\multirow{3}{7em}{ \centering True Value}
& \multirow{3}{4em}{\centering Method}
& \multicolumn{20}{c|}{ Sample Size ${n}$} \\
\cline{3-22}
& & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{\makecell{ ${50}$}}
& \multicolumn{5}{c|}{\makecell{ ${100}$}}
& \multicolumn{5}{c|}{\makecell{ ${500}$}}
& \multicolumn{5}{c|}{\makecell{ ${1000}$}}\\

\cline{3-22}
 & &  AIC & AIC$_{c}$ & BIC & LASSO & LASSO $^{*}$ &  AIC & AIC$_{c}$ & BIC & LASSO & LASSO $^{*}$&  AIC & AIC$_{c}$ & BIC & LASSO & LASSO $^{*}$&  AIC & AIC$_{c}$ & BIC & LASSO & LASSO $^{*}$\\
\hline \hline
${\phi=0.2}$ 
&\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
One-step\\  Two-step
\end{tabular}
%mean of beta
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$
\end{tabular} 
%sd of beta
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$
\end{tabular} 
%mean of phi 
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$    
\end{tabular}
%sd of phi
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$ 
\end{tabular} 
%sd of phi
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$ 
\end{tabular} 

%mean of beta
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$
\end{tabular} 
%sd of beta
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$
\end{tabular} 
%mean of phi 
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$    
\end{tabular}
%sd of phi
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$ 
\end{tabular} 
%sd of phi
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$ 
\end{tabular} 


%mean of beta
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$
\end{tabular} 
%sd of beta
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$
\end{tabular} 
%mean of phi 
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$    
\end{tabular}
%sd of phi
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$ 
\end{tabular} 
%sd of phi
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$ 
\end{tabular} 


%mean of beta
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$
\end{tabular} 
%sd of beta
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$
\end{tabular} 
%mean of phi 
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$    
\end{tabular}
%sd of phi
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$ 
\end{tabular} 
%sd of phi
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$ 
\end{tabular} 
\\ \hline \hline

${\phi=0.2}$ 
&\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
One-step\\  Two-step
\end{tabular}
%mean of beta
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$
\end{tabular} 
%sd of beta
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$
\end{tabular} 
%mean of phi 
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$    
\end{tabular}
%sd of phi
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$ 
\end{tabular} 
%sd of phi
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$ 
\end{tabular} 

%mean of beta
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$
\end{tabular} 
%sd of beta
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$
\end{tabular} 
%mean of phi 
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$    
\end{tabular}
%sd of phi
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$ 
\end{tabular} 
%sd of phi
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$ 
\end{tabular} 


%mean of beta
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$
\end{tabular} 
%sd of beta
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$
\end{tabular} 
%mean of phi 
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$    
\end{tabular}
%sd of phi
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$ 
\end{tabular} 
%sd of phi
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$ 
\end{tabular} 


%mean of beta
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$
\end{tabular} 
%sd of beta
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$
\end{tabular} 
%mean of phi 
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$    
\end{tabular}
%sd of phi
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$ 
\end{tabular} 
%sd of phi
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$ 
\end{tabular} 
\\ \hline \hline

${\phi=0.2}$ 
&\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
One-step\\  Two-step
\end{tabular}
%mean of beta
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$
\end{tabular} 
%sd of beta
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$
\end{tabular} 
%mean of phi 
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$    
\end{tabular}
%sd of phi
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$ 
\end{tabular} 
%sd of phi
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$ 
\end{tabular} 

%mean of beta
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$
\end{tabular} 
%sd of beta
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$
\end{tabular} 
%mean of phi 
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$    
\end{tabular}
%sd of phi
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$ 
\end{tabular} 
%sd of phi
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$ 
\end{tabular} 


%mean of beta
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$
\end{tabular} 
%sd of beta
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$
\end{tabular} 
%mean of phi 
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$    
\end{tabular}
%sd of phi
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$ 
\end{tabular} 
%sd of phi
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$ 
\end{tabular} 


%mean of beta
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$
\end{tabular} 
%sd of beta
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$
\end{tabular} 
%mean of phi 
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$    
\end{tabular}
%sd of phi
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$ 
\end{tabular} 
%sd of phi
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$ 
\end{tabular} 
\\ \hline \hline


${\phi=0.2}$ 
&\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
One-step\\  Two-step
\end{tabular}
%mean of beta
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$
\end{tabular} 
%sd of beta
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$
\end{tabular} 
%mean of phi 
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$    
\end{tabular}
%sd of phi
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$ 
\end{tabular} 
%sd of phi
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$ 
\end{tabular} 

%mean of beta
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$
\end{tabular} 
%sd of beta
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$
\end{tabular} 
%mean of phi 
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$    
\end{tabular}
%sd of phi
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$ 
\end{tabular} 
%sd of phi
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$ 
\end{tabular} 


%mean of beta
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$
\end{tabular} 
%sd of beta
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$
\end{tabular} 
%mean of phi 
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$    
\end{tabular}
%sd of phi
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$ 
\end{tabular} 
%sd of phi
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$ 
\end{tabular} 


%mean of beta
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$
\end{tabular} 
%sd of beta
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$
\end{tabular} 
%mean of phi 
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$    
\end{tabular}
%sd of phi
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$ 
\end{tabular} 
%sd of phi
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$ 
\end{tabular} 
\\ \hline \hline

${\phi=0.2}$ 
&\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
One-step\\  Two-step
\end{tabular}
%mean of beta
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$
\end{tabular} 
%sd of beta
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$
\end{tabular} 
%mean of phi 
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$    
\end{tabular}
%sd of phi
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$ 
\end{tabular} 
%sd of phi
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$ 
\end{tabular} 

%mean of beta
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$
\end{tabular} 
%sd of beta
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$
\end{tabular} 
%mean of phi 
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$    
\end{tabular}
%sd of phi
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$ 
\end{tabular} 
%sd of phi
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$ 
\end{tabular} 


%mean of beta
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$
\end{tabular} 
%sd of beta
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$
\end{tabular} 
%mean of phi 
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$    
\end{tabular}
%sd of phi
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$ 
\end{tabular} 
%sd of phi
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$ 
\end{tabular} 


%mean of beta
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$
\end{tabular} 
%sd of beta
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$
\end{tabular} 
%mean of phi 
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$    
\end{tabular}
%sd of phi
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$ 
\end{tabular} 
%sd of phi
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$ 
\end{tabular} 
\\ \hline \hline

${\phi=0.2}$ 
&\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
One-step\\  Two-step
\end{tabular}
%mean of beta
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$
\end{tabular} 
%sd of beta
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$
\end{tabular} 
%mean of phi 
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$    
\end{tabular}
%sd of phi
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$ 
\end{tabular} 
%sd of phi
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$ 
\end{tabular} 

%mean of beta
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$
\end{tabular} 
%sd of beta
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$
\end{tabular} 
%mean of phi 
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$    
\end{tabular}
%sd of phi
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$ 
\end{tabular} 
%sd of phi
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$ 
\end{tabular} 


%mean of beta
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$
\end{tabular} 
%sd of beta
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$
\end{tabular} 
%mean of phi 
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$    
\end{tabular}
%sd of phi
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$ 
\end{tabular} 
%sd of phi
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$ 
\end{tabular} 


%mean of beta
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$
\end{tabular} 
%sd of beta
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$
\end{tabular} 
%mean of phi 
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$    
\end{tabular}
%sd of phi
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$ 
\end{tabular} 
%sd of phi
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$\\${0.9254 \pm 0.9254 }$ 
\end{tabular} 
\\ \hline \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{center}
%\label{table:table2.1}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Which document class do you use? Which options? Anyway, you should never use  `adjustbox` with a table

Comment: Your best bet is to subdivide the table into smaller ones. Which contents should go for which of the new tables depends on your discipline and the way you want to present concepts

Comment: In my opinion, you should redesign your table, with the sample sizes n=50, 100, &c. n being substitles in the table, and the corresponding values being subtables one below the other.

Comment: Also :(1) Reduce the number of decimals . You lost something important changing 0.9254 to 0.925, or just 0.92? (2) Use the `booktabs` package. This will not increase the font size, but not jailed numbers are more readable (and the table is more elegant) (3) Do not use tabular to make cells. This only helps to make also unreadable the source.

Comment: Entirely unrelated to the issue itself: please clean up your preamble. Especially, do not load packages more than once. Also do not use adjustbox on tables. This will only result in inconsistent and sometimes illegibly small font sizes.

Comment: Did you come up with this code? Or did you use a software tool such as tablegenerator.com?

Comment: Will your actual table contain more rows than the 6 (12) you currently are included? What kind of numbers will be in your actual table? Will you include numbers with even more integer and/or decimal places than you already have?

Answer (score 7):

Some comments and suggestions:

- As you and others have already noted, the table is simply far too big to fit on a single page. Breaking it up into 4 subtables, corresponding to n=50, 100, 500, and 1000, would seem to be an absolute necessity.
- Before proceeding to the details of the table, I can't help but help but remark that the preamble of your document is a dreadful mess. There can be no justification for loading packages twice, three times, or four or even more times. Load the `hyperref` package *last*. Learn to use the `geometry` package. And, don't load the obsolete and deprecated `subfigure` package.

I've tried to improve the preamble situation in the code below. The sooner you can convince yourself that you don't need all of the remaining `\usepackage` directives, the better.

- I suggest you switch from a `sidewaystable` to a `table` environment. Load the `subcaption` package and use its `subtable` machiner. Do use `tabular*` instead of `tabular` for the four subtables. With these adjustments, you'll still need to switch to a `\small` relative font size; however, that shouldn't imperil the basic legibility of the tabular material. Observe that the `adjustbox`-related material is gone.
- Do give the tables a much more open look by (a) omitting all vertical lines and (b) using fewer, but well spaced, horizontal lines generated by `\toprule`, `\midrule`, and `\bottomrule`.
- Try to reduce code clutter as much as possible. E.g., instead of `True Value`, just write `$\phi$`. Do also try to mend your habit of enclosing lots of math-mode objects unnecessarily in pairs of curly braces. E.g., instead of `${50}$`, just write `$50$`.

The following screenshot shows the first few rows of the resulting subtables (a) and (c).

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[section]
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[section]

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{10}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{rotfloat}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{setspace}         
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{collcell}

\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{subcaption} % <-- new

\pagestyle{myheadings} 
\usepackage[letterpaper,textheight=9in,textwidth=6.5in]{geometry}

\usepackage{hyperref} % load this package _LAST_

\newcommand{\mbf}[1]{\mbox{\boldmath $#1$}}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[p] % place the float on a page by itself
\caption{Means and standard deviations of \dots} 
   %% ironically, you don't show standard deviations anywhere in the tables
\label{table:2.1}

\small
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}

\begin{subtable}{\textwidth}
\caption{$n=50$}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} ll ccccc @{}}
\toprule
$\phi$ & Method & AIC & AIC$_{c}$ & BIC & LASSO & LASSO$^{*}$ 
\\
\midrule
$0.2$ 
&\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
One-step\\  Two-step
\end{tabular}
%mean of beta
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$
\end{tabular} 
%sd of beta
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$
\end{tabular} 
%mean of phi 
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$    
\end{tabular}
%sd of phi
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$ 
\end{tabular} 
%sd of phi
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$ 
\end{tabular} 
\\
\addlinespace
$0.4$ 
&\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
One-step\\  Two-step
\end{tabular}
%mean of beta
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$
\end{tabular} 
%sd of beta
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$
\end{tabular} 
%mean of phi 
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$    
\end{tabular}
%sd of phi
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$ 
\end{tabular} 
%sd of phi
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$ 
\end{tabular} 
\\
\addlinespace

$0.6$ 
&\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
One-step\\  Two-step
\end{tabular}
%mean of beta
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$
\end{tabular} 
%sd of beta
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$
\end{tabular} 
%mean of phi 
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$    
\end{tabular}
%sd of phi
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$ 
\end{tabular} 
%sd of phi
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$ 
\end{tabular} 
\\
\addlinespace

$0.8$ 
&\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
One-step\\  Two-step
\end{tabular}
%mean of beta
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$
\end{tabular} 
%sd of beta
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$
\end{tabular} 
%mean of phi 
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$    
\end{tabular}
%sd of phi
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$ 
\end{tabular} 
%sd of phi
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$ 
\end{tabular} 
\\
\addlinespace

$0.9$ 
&\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
One-step\\  Two-step
\end{tabular}
%mean of beta
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$
\end{tabular} 
%sd of beta
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$
\end{tabular} 
%mean of phi 
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$    
\end{tabular}
%sd of phi
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$ 
\end{tabular} 
%sd of phi
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$ 
\end{tabular} 
\\
\addlinespace

$0.95$ 
&\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
One-step\\  Two-step
\end{tabular}
%mean of beta
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$
\end{tabular} 
%sd of beta
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$
\end{tabular} 
%mean of phi 
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$    
\end{tabular}
%sd of phi
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$ 
\end{tabular} 
%sd of phi
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$ 
\end{tabular} 
\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{subtable}
 
 
 
%%%%%%%



\vspace{1cm}
\begin{subtable}{\textwidth}
\caption{$n=100$}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} ll ccccc @{}}
\toprule
$\phi$ & Method & AIC & AIC$_{c}$ & BIC & LASSO & LASSO$^{*}$ 
\\
\midrule
$0.2$ 
&\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
One-step\\  Two-step
\end{tabular}
%mean of beta
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$
\end{tabular} 
%sd of beta
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$
\end{tabular} 
%mean of phi 
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$    
\end{tabular}
%sd of phi
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$ 
\end{tabular} 
%sd of phi
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$ 
\end{tabular} 
\\
\addlinespace
$0.4$ 
&\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
One-step\\  Two-step
\end{tabular}
%mean of beta
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$
\end{tabular} 
%sd of beta
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$
\end{tabular} 
%mean of phi 
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$    
\end{tabular}
%sd of phi
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$ 
\end{tabular} 
%sd of phi
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$ 
\end{tabular} 
\\
\addlinespace

$0.6$ 
&\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
One-step\\  Two-step
\end{tabular}
%mean of beta
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$
\end{tabular} 
%sd of beta
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$
\end{tabular} 
%mean of phi 
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$    
\end{tabular}
%sd of phi
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$ 
\end{tabular} 
%sd of phi
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$ 
\end{tabular} 
\\
\addlinespace

$0.8$ 
&\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
One-step\\  Two-step
\end{tabular}
%mean of beta
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$
\end{tabular} 
%sd of beta
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$
\end{tabular} 
%mean of phi 
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$    
\end{tabular}
%sd of phi
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$ 
\end{tabular} 
%sd of phi
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$ 
\end{tabular} 
\\
\addlinespace

$0.9$ 
&\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
One-step\\  Two-step
\end{tabular}
%mean of beta
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$
\end{tabular} 
%sd of beta
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$
\end{tabular} 
%mean of phi 
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$    
\end{tabular}
%sd of phi
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$ 
\end{tabular} 
%sd of phi
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$ 
\end{tabular} 
\\
\addlinespace

$0.95$ 
&\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
One-step\\  Two-step
\end{tabular}
%mean of beta
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$
\end{tabular} 
%sd of beta
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$
\end{tabular} 
%mean of phi 
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$    
\end{tabular}
%sd of phi
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$ 
\end{tabular} 
%sd of phi
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$ 
\end{tabular} 
\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{subtable}


\end{table}

\begin{table}[p]
\ContinuedFloat
\caption{Means and standard deviations of \dots, continued}

\small
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}

\begin{subtable}{\textwidth}
\caption{$n=500$}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} ll ccccc @{}}
\toprule
$\phi$ & Method & AIC & AIC$_{c}$ & BIC & LASSO & LASSO$^{*}$ 
\\
\midrule
$0.2$ 
&\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
One-step\\  Two-step
\end{tabular}
%mean of beta
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$
\end{tabular} 
%sd of beta
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$
\end{tabular} 
%mean of phi 
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$    
\end{tabular}
%sd of phi
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$ 
\end{tabular} 
%sd of phi
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$ 
\end{tabular} 
\\
\addlinespace
$0.4$ 
&\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
One-step\\  Two-step
\end{tabular}
%mean of beta
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$
\end{tabular} 
%sd of beta
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$
\end{tabular} 
%mean of phi 
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$    
\end{tabular}
%sd of phi
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$ 
\end{tabular} 
%sd of phi
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$ 
\end{tabular} 
\\
\addlinespace

$0.6$ 
&\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
One-step\\  Two-step
\end{tabular}
%mean of beta
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$
\end{tabular} 
%sd of beta
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$
\end{tabular} 
%mean of phi 
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$    
\end{tabular}
%sd of phi
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$ 
\end{tabular} 
%sd of phi
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$ 
\end{tabular} 
\\
\addlinespace

$0.8$ 
&\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
One-step\\  Two-step
\end{tabular}
%mean of beta
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$
\end{tabular} 
%sd of beta
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$
\end{tabular} 
%mean of phi 
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$    
\end{tabular}
%sd of phi
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$ 
\end{tabular} 
%sd of phi
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$ 
\end{tabular} 
\\
\addlinespace

$0.9$ 
&\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
One-step\\  Two-step
\end{tabular}
%mean of beta
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$
\end{tabular} 
%sd of beta
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$
\end{tabular} 
%mean of phi 
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$    
\end{tabular}
%sd of phi
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$ 
\end{tabular} 
%sd of phi
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$ 
\end{tabular} 
\\
\addlinespace

$0.95$ 
&\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
One-step\\  Two-step
\end{tabular}
%mean of beta
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$
\end{tabular} 
%sd of beta
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$
\end{tabular} 
%mean of phi 
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$    
\end{tabular}
%sd of phi
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$ 
\end{tabular} 
%sd of phi
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$ 
\end{tabular} 
\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{subtable}
 
 
 
%%%%%%%



\vspace{1cm}
\begin{subtable}{\textwidth}
\caption{$n=1000$}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} ll ccccc @{}}
\toprule
$\phi$ & Method & AIC & AIC$_{c}$ & BIC & LASSO & LASSO$^{*}$ 
\\
\midrule
$0.2$ 
&\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
One-step\\  Two-step
\end{tabular}
%mean of beta
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$
\end{tabular} 
%sd of beta
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$
\end{tabular} 
%mean of phi 
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$    
\end{tabular}
%sd of phi
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$ 
\end{tabular} 
%sd of phi
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$ 
\end{tabular} 
\\
\addlinespace
$0.4$ 
&\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
One-step\\  Two-step
\end{tabular}
%mean of beta
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$
\end{tabular} 
%sd of beta
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$
\end{tabular} 
%mean of phi 
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$    
\end{tabular}
%sd of phi
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$ 
\end{tabular} 
%sd of phi
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$ 
\end{tabular} 
\\
\addlinespace

$0.6$ 
&\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
One-step\\  Two-step
\end{tabular}
%mean of beta
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$
\end{tabular} 
%sd of beta
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$
\end{tabular} 
%mean of phi 
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$    
\end{tabular}
%sd of phi
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$ 
\end{tabular} 
%sd of phi
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$ 
\end{tabular} 
\\
\addlinespace

$0.8$ 
&\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
One-step\\  Two-step
\end{tabular}
%mean of beta
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$
\end{tabular} 
%sd of beta
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$
\end{tabular} 
%mean of phi 
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$    
\end{tabular}
%sd of phi
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$ 
\end{tabular} 
%sd of phi
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$ 
\end{tabular} 
\\
\addlinespace

$0.9$ 
&\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
One-step\\  Two-step
\end{tabular}
%mean of beta
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$
\end{tabular} 
%sd of beta
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$
\end{tabular} 
%mean of phi 
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$    
\end{tabular}
%sd of phi
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$ 
\end{tabular} 
%sd of phi
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$ 
\end{tabular} 
\\
\addlinespace

$0.95$ 
&\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
One-step\\  Two-step
\end{tabular}
%mean of beta
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$
\end{tabular} 
%sd of beta
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$
\end{tabular} 
%mean of phi 
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$    
\end{tabular}
%sd of phi
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$ 
\end{tabular} 
%sd of phi
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
$0.925\pm 0.925$\\$0.925\pm 0.925$ 
\end{tabular} 
\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{subtable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

As supplement to nice [@MIco answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/547622/manage-large-table/547647#547647). With using loaded `multirow` package and after reorganizing rows all nested `\tabulars` in the table the code tables code can become quite shorter:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,textheight=9in,textwidth=6.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{eurosym, pifont}
\usepackage{bm}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[section]
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[section]
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{10}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{indentfirst}

\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs, collcell, longtable, makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\usepackage{rotfloat}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{subcaption} % <-- new

\pagestyle{myheadings}

\usepackage{hyperref} % load this package _LAST_

\newcommand{\mbf}[1]{\mbox{\boldmath $#1$}}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[p] 
\caption{Means and standard deviations of \dots}
\label{table:2.1}

\small
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}

\begin{subtable}{\textwidth}
\caption{$n=50$}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} ll *{5}{>{$}c<{$} }}
    \toprule
$\phi$  & Method        & \text{AIC}        & \text{AIC}_{c} 
        & \text{BIC}    & \text{LASSO}      & \text{LASSO}^{*}  \\
    \midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{$0.2$}
    &   One-step        & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925
    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925  \\
    &   Two-step        & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925
    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925  \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{*}{$0.4$}
    &   One-step        & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925
    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925  \\
    &   Two-step        & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925
    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925  \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{*}{$0.6$}
    &   One-step        & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925
    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925  \\
    &   Two-step        & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925
    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925  \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{*}{$0.8$}
    &   One-step        & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925
    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925  \\
    &   Two-step        & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925
    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925  \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{*}{$0.9$}
    &   One-step        & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925
    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925  \\
    &   Two-step        & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925
    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925  \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{*}{$0.95$}
    &   One-step        & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925
    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925  \\
    &   Two-step        & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925
    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925  \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{subtable}

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{subtable}{\textwidth}
\caption{$n=100$}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} ll *{5}{>{$}c<{$} }}
    \toprule
$\phi$  & Method        & \text{AIC}        & \text{AIC}_{c}
        & \text{BIC}    & \text{LASSO}      & \text{LASSO}^{*}  \\
    \midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{$0.2$}
    &   One-step        & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925
    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925  \\
    &   Two-step        & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925
    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925  \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{*}{$0.4$}
    &   One-step        & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925
    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925  \\
    &   Two-step        & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925
    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925  \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{*}{$0.6$}
    &   One-step        & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925
    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925  \\
    &   Two-step        & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925
    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925  \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{*}{$0.8$}
    &   One-step        & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925
    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925  \\
    &   Two-step        & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925
    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925  \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{*}{$0.9$}
    &   One-step        & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925
    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925  \\
    &   Two-step        & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925
    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925  \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{*}{$0.95$}
    &   One-step        & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925
    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925  \\
    &   Two-step        & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925
    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925  \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{subtable}
    \end{table}


    \begin{table}[p] 
\ContinuedFloat
\caption{Means and standard deviations of \dots}
\label{table:2.1}

\small
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}

\begin{subtable}{\textwidth}
\caption{$n=500$}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} ll *{5}{>{$}c<{$} }}
    \toprule
$\phi$  & Method        & \text{AIC}        & \text{AIC}_{c}
        & \text{BIC}    & \text{LASSO}      & \text{LASSO}^{*}  \\
    \midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{$0.2$}
    &   One-step        & 0.925\pm 0.925  & 0.925\pm 0.925
    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925  & 0.925\pm 0.925  \\
    &   Two-step        & 0.925\pm 0.925  & 0.925\pm 0.925
    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925  & 0.925\pm 0.925  \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{*}{$0.4$}
    &   One-step        & 0.925\pm 0.925  & 0.925\pm 0.925
    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925  & 0.925\pm 0.925  \\
    &   Two-step        & 0.925\pm 0.925  & 0.925\pm 0.925
    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925  & 0.925\pm 0.925  \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{*}{$0.6$}
    &   One-step        & 0.925\pm 0.925  & 0.925\pm 0.925
    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925  & 0.925\pm 0.925  \\
    &   Two-step        & 0.925\pm 0.925  & 0.925\pm 0.925
    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925  & 0.925\pm 0.925  \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{*}{$0.8$}
    &   One-step        & 0.925\pm 0.925  & 0.925\pm 0.925
    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925  & 0.925\pm 0.925  \\
    &   Two-step        & 0.925\pm 0.925  & 0.925\pm 0.925
    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925  & 0.925\pm 0.925  \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{*}{$0.9$}
    &   One-step        & 0.925\pm 0.925  & 0.925\pm 0.925
    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925  & 0.925\pm 0.925  \\
    &   Two-step        & 0.925\pm 0.925  & 0.925\pm 0.925
    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925  & 0.925\pm 0.925  \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{*}{$0.95$}
    &   One-step        & 0.925\pm 0.925  & 0.925\pm 0.925
    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925  & 0.925\pm 0.925  \\
    &   Two-step        & 0.925\pm 0.925  & 0.925\pm 0.925
    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925  & 0.925\pm 0.925  \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{subtable}

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{subtable}{\textwidth}
\caption{$n=1000$}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} ll *{5}{>{$}c<{$} }}
    \toprule
$\phi$  & Method        & \text{AIC}        & \text{AIC}_{c}
        & \text{BIC}    & \text{LASSO}      & \text{LASSO}^{*}  \\
    \midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{$0.2$}
    &   One-step        & 0.925\pm 0.925  & 0.925\pm 0.925
    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925  & 0.925\pm 0.925  \\
    &   Two-step        & 0.925\pm 0.925  & 0.925\pm 0.925
    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925  & 0.925\pm 0.925  \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{*}{$0.4$}
    &   One-step        & 0.925\pm 0.925  & 0.925\pm 0.925
    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925  & 0.925\pm 0.925  \\
    &   Two-step        & 0.925\pm 0.925  & 0.925\pm 0.925
    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925  & 0.925\pm 0.925  \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{*}{$0.6$}
    &   One-step        & 0.925\pm 0.925  & 0.925\pm 0.925
    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925  & 0.925\pm 0.925  \\
    &   Two-step        & 0.925\pm 0.925  & 0.925\pm 0.925
    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925  & 0.925\pm 0.925  \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{*}{$0.8$}
    &   One-step        & 0.925\pm 0.925  & 0.925\pm 0.925
    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925  & 0.925\pm 0.925  \\
    &   Two-step        & 0.925\pm 0.925  & 0.925\pm 0.925
    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925  & 0.925\pm 0.925  \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{*}{$0.9$}
    &   One-step        & 0.925\pm 0.925  & 0.925\pm 0.925
    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925  & 0.925\pm 0.925  \\
    &   Two-step        & 0.925\pm 0.925  & 0.925\pm 0.925
    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925  & 0.925\pm 0.925  \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{*}{$0.95$}
    &   One-step        & 0.925\pm 0.925  & 0.925\pm 0.925
    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925  & 0.925\pm 0.925  \\
    &   Two-step        & 0.925\pm 0.925  & 0.925\pm 0.925
    & 0.925\pm 0.925    & 0.925\pm 0.925  & 0.925\pm 0.925  \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{subtable}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for trying to disentangle the `tabular` environments and for using automatic math mode whenever possible. Before I posted my answer, I debated whether I should point out that the table doesn't show *any* standard deviations, the claim in the `\caption` notwithstanding. In the end, though, I chose not to mention this concern, as I suspect the OP hasn't actually fully made up his/her mind yet on how to show the numbers. If this were my table, I would probably transpose much of each `tabular*` environment, to show the mean in the first row and the std. dev. (in parens) in the 2nd row.

Comment: @Mico, as I see the OP 's table, (s)he provide dummy numbers in tables body. The problem you pointed out (in this matter I agree with you) seems to not bother OP or it be addressed in the next her/his question :-)